# How to get the bounding box coordinates for the detected object

Tags: tensorflow, keras, object-detection, bounding-box, tensorflow2.0

I am new to tensorflow.am very confusing to get the bounding box coordinates for the detected object.how to get the bounding box to the detected object.this is my code  please help!!

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_hub as hub
import os
import cv2

test_dir=os.getcwd()+'/test_img'
test_img=os.listdir(test_dir)
def convert_to_array(img):
    im = cv2.imread(img)
    img_ = Image.fromarray(im, 'RGB')
    image = img_.resize((224,224))
    return np.array(image)

def get_cell_name(label):
    if label==0:
        return "daisy"
    if label==1:
        return "dandelion"

model = tf.keras.experimental.load_from_saved_model('E:/model/flowers.h5', custom_objects={'KerasLayer':hub.KerasLayer})
model.build((None, 224, 224, 3))

for img in test_img:
    file = os.path.join(test_dir, img)
    ar=convert_to_array(file)
    ar=ar/255
    label=1
    a=[]
    a.append(ar)
    a=np.array(a)
    score=model.predict(a,verbose=1)
    print(score)
    label_index=np.argmax(score)
    print(label_index)
    acc=np.max(score)
    Cell=get_cell_name(label_index)
    print(Cell,acc)
    img = cv2.imread(file)
    text='this is '+Cell
    cv2.putText(img,text, (5,15), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, 255)
    cv2.imshow('image',img)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

is you asking about this structure.

````
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    hub.KerasLayer(MODULE_HANDLE, output_shape=[FV_SIZE],
                   trainable=do_fine_tuning),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(rate=0.2),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(train_generator.num_classes, activation='softmax',
                          kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l2(0.0001))
])
model.build((None,)+IMAGE_SIZE+(3,))
model.summary()```
````

Comment: What is your deep learning network?

Comment: Convolutional Neural Network

Comment: Can you provide network structure? Does it have regression head for bounding box?

Comment: network structure means what is it structure of the network layers!!!

Comment: update the layers structure please check it

Comment: This is a classification network but not a object detection network.

Comment: then which network is suitable for object detection

Comment: You can try RCNN, RetinaNet, Yolo.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use a classification network. A classification network will classify an entire image into one of the classes.

For detecting objects in image, try networks such as RCNN, RetinaNet, Yolo etc.

Comment: can i add regression head for bounding box in the classification model.Is it possible